# PowerShell: How to concatenate results in ForEach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I want to group the section in the 2nd ForEach. How do I do the equivalent of $result = $result + ...?

```powershell
$clusters = "cluster1", "cluster2"
ForEach ($item in $clusters)
{
  $clusterNodes = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $item  ;
  $clusterNodes|select Cluster,NodeName, State|Sort-Object NodeName|Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize;

  ForEach ($vm in $clusterNodes)
  {
    $result = Get-VM -ComputerName $vm.Name |select VMName, ComputerName, PrimaryOperationalStatus, State, Path, CreationTime, Uptime, IntegrationServicesVersion,ProcessorCount, DynamicMemoryEnabled, MemoryMinimum,MemoryMaximum     |Sort-Object VMName|Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize;
    $result
  }
}
```

For example, in my output, each section has its own results. I want to combine the results, sort them, count them, and display them as one result, not x times the number of $clusters.

```
Cluster          NodeName State
-------          -------- -----
CLUSTER1         SERVER1      Up
CLUSTER1         SERVER2      Up
CLUSTER1         SERVER3      Up
CLUSTER1         SERVER4      Up


VMName  ComputerName PrimaryOperationalStatus   State Path                              CreationTime          Uptime      IntegrationServicesVersion ProcessorCount Dynam
------  ------------ ------------------------   ----- ----                              ------------          ------      -------------------------- -------------- -----
XYZ080  SERVER1                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\XYZ080  11/15/2013 2:16:39 PM 3.13:46:52  6.2.9200.16384                          4  True
XYZ019  SERVER1                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\XYZ019  11/6/2013 10:24:58 AM 68.07:02:32 6.2.9200.20655                          2 False
XYZ021A SERVER1                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\ XYZ021A 11/1/2013 10:33:20 AM 68.07:02:01 6.2.9200.20655                          6 False


VMName  ComputerName PrimaryOperationalStatus   State Path                              CreationTime           Uptime      IntegrationServicesVersion ProcessorCount Dyna
------  ------------ ------------------------   ----- ----                              ------------           ------      -------------------------- -------------- ----
XYZ078  SERVER2                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\XYZ078  10/30/2013 11:20:05 AM 61.04:32:55 6.2.9200.20655                          4 Fals
NXYZ001 SERVER2                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\volume1\NXYZ001 11/7/2013 8:54:29 AM   1.01:55:10  6.2.9200.16384                          2 Fals
ABC051  SERVER2                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\volume1\ABC051  11/1/2013 2:52:24 PM   1.06:57:57  6.2.9200.20655                          4 Fals
```

I want it to appear like the following:

```
Cluster          NodeName State
-------          -------- -----
CLUSTER1         SERVER1      Up
CLUSTER1         SERVER2      Up
CLUSTER1         SERVER3      Up
CLUSTER1         SERVER4      Up


VMName  ComputerName PrimaryOperationalStatus   State Path                              CreationTime          Uptime      IntegrationServicesVersion ProcessorCount Dynam
------  ------------ ------------------------   ----- ----                              ------------          ------      -------------------------- -------------- -----
XYZ080  SERVER1                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\XYZ080  11/15/2013 2:16:39 PM 3.13:46:52  6.2.9200.16384                          4  True
XYZ019  SERVER1                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\XYZ019  11/6/2013 10:24:58 AM 68.07:02:32 6.2.9200.20655                          2 False
XYZ021A SERVER1                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\ XYZ021A 11/1/2013 10:33:20 AM 68.07:02:01 6.2.9200.20655                          6 False
XYZ078  SERVER2                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\XYZ078  10/30/2013 11:20:05 AM 61.04:32:55 6.2.9200.20655                          4 False
NXYZ001 SERVER2                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\volume1\NXYZ001 11/7/2013 8:54:29 AM   1.01:55:10  6.2.9200.16384                          2 False
ABC051  SERVER2                             Ok Running C:\ClusterStorage\volume1\ABC051  11/1/2013 2:52:24 PM   1.06:57:57  6.2.9200.20655                          4 Fals
```

Comment: When I shorten the `$result = Get-VM -ComputerName $vm.Name |select VMName, ComputerName, PrimaryOperationalStatus, State, Path, CreationTime, Uptime, IntegrationServicesVersion,ProcessorCount, DynamicMemoryEnabled, MemoryMinimum,MemoryMaximum     |Sort-Object VMName|Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize;` command to `$result = Get-VM -ComputerName $vm.Name | select VMName, ComputerName, PrimaryOperationalStatus,State;` the results are expected.  It's when I add more fields to the select statement that it goes all crazy on me

Comment: Now that I've formatted your code and removed some blank lines that I take it were an artifact of copying the output, I noticed that the foreach loops are nested, which wasn't clear when the code was flat. So, I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Do you want one `Cluster NodeName State` listing and one `VMName ComputerName PrimaryOperationalStatus State Path` listing for each iteration of the outer loop, or a combined `Cluster NodeName State` listing followed by a combined `VMName ComputerName PrimaryOperationalStatus State Path` listing, gathered from all iterations?

Comment: I want it to go through each cluster, and list all the nodes, as it does.  then it returns all the VMs in the nodes.  Since I have more than one cluster, it will do the same as above for each cluster.  Ideally, the results will be sorted by VM Name.

Comment: If I interpret that correctly, that's what my answer does--one list of nodes and one list of all the VMs for *each* cluster (not a unified list of all nodes in all clusters and a unified list of all VMs in all clusters). So, two listings for each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing **Format-Table** multiple times, so you're getting a new set of formatted output each time. Instead of a **foreach** that contains the **Format-Table** filter, use a single pipeline with **Format-Table** at the end.

Also, there are a couple of redundancies in your code:

- There's no need to **select** first and then pipe to **Format-Table**. You can just list the properties you want to output in the **Format-Table** statement.

  There's no need to assign the results to a variable unless you plan on reusing those results elsewhere in your code. If you just want to output the results once, omit the assignment to a variable and the results will automatically be sent to the standard output stream.

Replace the inner **foreach** loop with this:

```powershell
$clusterNodes | %{Get-VM -ComputerName $_.Name} | Sort-Object VMName `
| Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize VMName, ComputerName, PrimaryOperationalStatus, State, Path, CreationTime, Uptime, IntegrationServicesVersion,ProcessorCount, DynamicMemoryEnabled, MemoryMinimum,MemoryMaximum
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure where I'm placing your code within mine.  What am I replacing?  Thanks again for the help, I'm new to PowerShell.

Comment: It's meant to replace the second **foreach** loop. BTW, I noticed an error--I forgot to replace `$vm.Name` with `$_.Name`. I'll update the answer.